# python classes update value of self

Tags: function, python-3.x, methods

I am writing a method in a class that is supposed to update `self` and return a new `self`. It looks like this:

```
def fill(self, x, y)
    some code to update self
    return self
```

In this case, `self` is a matrix.

My idea was when I use `self.fill(x, y)`, `self` should be updated based on `x` and `y`. However, Python tends to ignore `s.fill(x, y)` and only update if I use `s=s.fill(x,y)` for a given matrix `s`.

I also tried to remove `return` from my function, but `s.fill(x, y)` is still ignored and `s=s.fill(x, y)` returns an error.

I am not sure how to let Python update the value of `self` itself (a bit similar to `list.append`, but unfortunately I could not find the source code for `append`).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "update `self`"? Change it's value? If so, how is the value determined/stored?

Comment: you'll have to show the code that you replaced with `some code to update self`. might have something with how you are changing the values (ie, you might not actually be changing anything in place)

Comment: self is the object itself, the function or method I defined in a class looks like this:

Comment: def fill(self, x, y, color):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.color=color           oldcolor = s[x][y]
            s[x][y] = color
            if x > 0: # Check up
                if s[x-1][y] == oldcolor:
                    fill(s, x-1, y, color)

Comment: if y < len(s[0])-1: # Check right
                if s[x][y+1] == oldcolor:
                    fill(s, x, y+1, color)
            if x < len(s)-1: # Check down
                if s[x+1][y] == oldcolor:
                    fill(s, x+1, y, color)
            if y > 0: #Check left
                if s[x][y-1] == oldcolor:
                    fill(s, x, y-1, color)
        self= fill(self, x, y, color)
        return self

Comment: this works when i type for a given matrix s: s=s.fill(x,y,color). But i want it to work just by typing s.fill(x,y,color) (that it updates the original matrix s)